# jqueryui switchClass callback

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm having a problem running a function after a jquery ui switchclass effect is completed.

looking into the [manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) it describes that

```
.switchClass( removeClassName, addClassName [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

but when trying to run a:

```
$("#main").switchClass('primary','secondary','slow',runAfterComplete());
```

with a

```
function runAfterComplete(){
    console.log("switchclass completed");
}
```

it runs it before it is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference(`runAfterComplete`) as the callback, in your case you are invoking(`()` at the end) the `runAfterComplete` function and the value returned from it(`undefined`) as the callback to the `switchClass` method

```
$("#main").switchClass('primary','secondary','slow',runAfterComplete);
```

Comment: plain and simple :)
thanks!

is there a way to send a parameter with runAfterComplete after all?

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#main").switchClass('primary','secondary','slow', function() {console.log("switchclass completed");});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: I just prefer using an anonymous function as a callback rather than a function reference.

Comment: Sooo, how does that answer the question?